# OpenCL overhead by kernel invocation

Tags: gpu, opencl

I want to measure the execution time of a OpenCL kernel in a loop. When I use `clGetEventProfilingInfo()` to measure the time for enqueueing, submitting and starting the kernel, I encountered an massive overhead for the time between kernel submission and the start of execution on the device, compared to the actual execution time. I use the following structure to profile the kernel:

```
cl_command_queue queue;
queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE, &err);

clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, kernel_data_d, CL_TRUE, 0,
                                      sizeof(cl_float) * kernel_data_size,
                                      kernel_data_h, 0, NULL, NULL);

for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {

  cl_event test;

  clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &global, &local, 0, NULL, &test);

  clWaitForEvents(1 , &test);
  clFinish(queue);
  clGetEventProfilingInfo(test, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_SUBMIT, sizeof(time_start), &time_start, NULL);
  clGetEventProfilingInfo(test, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START, sizeof(time_end), &time_end, NULL);
  time_passed_kernel += (time_end-time_start)/1e6;
  clReleaseEvent(test);

}
```

It takes around 350ms on average for the execution start after the kernel has been submitted, and only 61ms on average for the actual execution. Is there any specific reason for this overhead? The data accessed by the kernel is on the GPU and the kernel has been compiled. Im using the integrated Adern 730 GPU of the Snapdragon 8 gen 1 SoC.

Comment: 350ms seems exceptionally high, is this for a "warm" compute kernel? (Don't include the overhead for the first time you run the kernel on that device in that host process.) What platform/device/driver? Is it a UMA/iGPU device, or does it have discrete VRAM? How are you dealing with memory buffers for ferrying data to and from the device, and could inefficiency there be the origin of your overhead? A good implementation for a modern iGPU will usually have sub-millisecond overhead, for dGPUs you need to add DMA/cache overhead, but you can still use CL kernels for realtime graphics. (<< 10ms)

Comment: @pmdj thanks for your detailed response! In every iteration I’m facing this overhead, so the kernel can be considered warm. I run the code on the Snapdragon 8 gen 1 tablet, which has a Adreno 730 iGPU. The data for the kernel is sent in one `EnqueueWriteBuffer()` call, which is a blocking command, so I assumed that the data is already on the GPU when running the first kernel.

Comment: @pmdj I just added the memory transfer to the code snipped above.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like im running into the internal power management of the Adreno GPU im using. Due to the GPU idles in between the kernel executions, the GPU probably turns to a lower power level and therefore takes a long time (couple of ms) get activated again for the next kernel.